# Get Facebook UID of user who browsed my page

Tags: facebook

I have a database of users. I have a list of facebook ID's who have liked our page on Facebook. I want to link these together.

I can send an email out to these users, asking them to like us on FB etc. When a user clicks on the "Facebook" button on the email, they are taken to a page that records who clicked the link. At the moment this page is blank, and it uses the JS SDK to get the logged in users Facebook uID, and then redirects to our facebook page. However, this requires that the user authorizes our app, which may turn many users off. Is there any way to get the uID of a user whos logged into facebook when they browse my page without using an app?

I've tried creating a Page Tab and linking to that, but the documentation implies that the user must also authorize the app the runs the Tab before the Tab/App is given the users ID.

Answer (score 0):

The authorization process is there for a reason, all users are anonymous before they authorize your app.

There is no way to get the ID without autzorization. And even with authorization, you only get an "App Scoped ID" now. See changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog